# Why won't my comment system work? [HTML]

Tags: html

I am a beginner in html, and I am beginning to develop my first website. I watched a video to learn to code a commentary system, here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4BkHj7Ws9U

My page does resemble what is shown in the video, but there is some errors, take a look at my webpage after watching the video, as you can see, there are errors:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<HTML>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label> Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"><br></label>
        <label> Message: <br><textarea cols="35" rows="5" name="mes"></textarea></label><br>
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
    </form>
</HTML>

<?php

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $text = $_POST["mes"];
    $post = $_POST["post"];

    if ($post){
        #WRITE DOWN COMMENTS#
        $write = fopen("com.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($write, "<u><b> $name</b></u><br>$text<br></br>");
        fclose($write);

        #DISPLAY COMMENTS#
        $read = fopen("com.txt", "r+t");
        echo "All comments:";
        while(!feof($read)){
            echo fread($read, 1024);
        }
        fclose($read);

    }
    else{
        #DISPLAY COMMENTS#
        $read = fopen("com.txt", "r+t");
        echo "All comments:<br>";
        while(!feof($read)){
            echo fread($read, 1024);
        }
        fclose($read);
    }
?>
```

Thank you for your help, sorry, I'm sort of a newbie at this.

Comment: Actually, no, we can't see the errors. Please explain them and post any error messages. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should communicate with a web developer.Because its not a proper way to develop a website.Learn first please!

Comment: Hi Blake! Nothing wrong with being a newbie. I'd recommend you **start small** and build the simplest working program you can, and work up from there. As a bonus, that doubles as an MCVE if you can't get it to work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like MAMP to run php code.
Or upload everything to a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your file as a PHP file.

Comment: What are you using to run your web server?